# Оптимизация модели ответа API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Модель ответа API, например:

```
      Class {
        String mySpeedVolMolHol;
        Stribg myLocationLatitudeLongitude;
        // И т.д.
       }
```

Или например:

```
      Class {
        String s;
        Stribg p;
        // И т.д. с публичными, человеко понятными 
          сеттерами  
      }
```

В случае со второй моделью у нас меньше данных передаются по сети. Нужна ли такая "оптимизация"? И насколько она будет продуктивной?

Будем стучатся к api. Каждые 3 секунды после выполнения предыдущего запроса. Возможно будет соккет...

Comment: В каком виде передаются данные? JSON? Можно задать атрибуты для сериализатора. Аналогично для xml. А можно передавать данные в формате, где нет имен полей/свойств (csv или разные бинарные).

Comment: Формат Будет Json

Comment: Интересно, есть ли возможность в GSON возможность десериализации без имен полей? т.е. придет массив Object`ов и мы знаем что элемент 1 это int, элемент 2 это String и т.д. и пишем какой то десериализатор для retrofit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто навесьте атрибуты на свойства класса:

```
public class Class
{
    [JsonProperty("s")]
    public String mySpeedVolMolHol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("p")]
    public String myLocationLatitudeLongitude { get; set; }
}
```

В результате будет получаться следующий json:

```
{"s":"...","p":"..."}
```

---

Нужна или нет эта оптимизация, зависит от ширины каналов вашей сети и сети ваших клиентов.

Не важно, что ваши пакеты весит 5-20 Кб. Важно общее количество передаваемых данных: может этих пакетов миллионы в секунду передаётся.

Так вот, если канал не загружен (и есть гарантированный запас на будущее) - можно не оптимизировать. Если канал загружен - вывод очевиден: в оптимизации есть смысл.

Причём у вас-то канал может быть толстый, а у ваших клиентов (которые деньги вам платят) он может быть тонким (или занят общением с другими поставщиками данных). И вашим клиентам может быть важна такая оптимизация.

Мониторьте загрузку сети, тестируйте. И тесно общайтесь с клиентами/заказчиками, интересуйтесь их делами.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, это вариант что бы API сериализовало с наименьшим кол-вом символов в именах полей. Главный вопрос наверное такой: Есть ли смысл от этик 20 кбайт(меньше даже, 5 наверное ) экономии в наше время?)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не стал выполнять такого рода "оптимизации" без явной необходимости. Это впоследствии может помешать разработке, так как имена полей неинформативные.

Comment: планировали только имена полей таким образом писать(именно модель API, а в клиентах все по феншую), а в конструкторе и в сеттерах геттерах было бы написано нормально. И в последующем бы было более менее нормально.. Ну и документация для новичков)